# Обнуление значений в translate3d через jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, transition

Делаю рулетку, передвигаю её с помощью `transform: translate3d` и после окончания передвижения обновляю данные внутри неё, но не могу обнулить значение translate3d без прокрутки анимации.

Вот код как я стартую рулетку

```
$('#casesCarusel').css({'transform': 'translate3d(-'+Math.rand(a, a+59)+'px, 0px, 0px)'});
```

Вот код как я проверяю окончание анимации

```
 $('#casesCarusel').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {
    console.log('finish');
});
```

Comment: Элементарно - transition указывает изменение какого свойства нужно анимировать, значит нужно чтобы в значении transition не оказалось transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

запустить код и кликнуть по зелёному квадрату

```js
 $(function() {

   $carusel = $('#casesCarusel');
   $carusel.on('click', function() {
     var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
     $carusel.css({
       'transition': 'all .' + a + 's ease-out',
       'transform': 'translate3d(-' + (a * 106) + 'px, 0px, 0px)'
     });
   })

   $carusel.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function(e) {


     $carusel.delay(1000).hide(600, function() {
       $carusel.css({
         'transform': 'none',
         'transition': 'none'
       }).delay(300).show(800);
     })

   });
 })
```

```css
.item {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 6px solid #006400;
  background-color: #228B22;
}
#casesCarusel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #228B22;
  width: 3000px;
  height: 110px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 102px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div id="casesCarusel">
    <span>Go</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена)

Answer (score 1):

На сколько мне известно функцию `transform: translate3d()` нельзя обнулить. Так что или просто быстро прокрутите рулетку обратно, либо с помощью `ajax` переподгрузите всю рулетку заново после прокрутки.